# number - All of these words ... are / is to express?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, grammatical-number

Should the plural **are** or singular **is** be used in the following?

> All of these words in me **are** / **is** to express how much I love you.

I think only **are** works, but I saw an ad that used **is** in this sentence.
And is "are to" natural? Should "are meant to" be used instead?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: All of the people on the street **is wearing|are wearing** hats?

Comment: **all** is the plural subject.

Comment: Four of my cassettes for your Madonna CD is a fair exchange. **Four** indicates plurality.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should definitely be **are** because that matches with the plural **words**.

If you saw an ad that used **is**, it was wrong.

> All of these words in me are to express how much I love you.

Although slightly unusual, there is nothing wrong with that sentence.

---

Variations, including your alternate suggestion and some that don't use **are** at all, include:

> All of these words express how much I love you.
>   All of these words are to express how much I love you.
>   All of these words are meant to express how much I love you.
>   All of these words in me express how much I love you.
>   All of these words are in me to express how much I love you.
>   All of these words in me are meant to express how much I love you.

Each of these is grammatical.

I can't tell you which version you should use. It depends on exactly what you're trying to say.